# Flutter: freezed custom operator == does not work as I accept

Tags: flutter, freezed

I am using freezed and I have list of object, I override my freezer class like this:

```
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      other is _ServiceItemModel &&
      id == other.id &&
      product.id == other.product.id &&
      product.externalId == other.product.externalId &&
      internalId == other.internalId &&
      identical(other, this);

  @override
  int get hashCode => [id, product.id, product.externalId, internalId].hashCode;
```

my question is why the value of `bool iseq = identical(servicesItem, oldService );` return false !

**servicesItem** and **oldService** are `List of ServiceItemModel`.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove this line

```
identical(other, this);
```

Comment: Not possible, I am using Redux, If I remove `identical` redux state don't be refresh

Comment: then what is your problem? `identical` can't return true for 2 variables.

Comment: My problem is exactly here , redux won't work without identical. If I remove it, my state doesn't change, I guess because Redux can understand the state is changed.

Comment: seems your implementation is wrong, maybe better to write your main implementation here, so that we can help.

Comment: If I check each item separately the equality is ok but in the list it is not working